# How to get full Estimote SDK instead of CoreSDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, estimote

I'm just started experimenting with Beacons and Android apps, I installed Estimote SDK by adding `compile 'com.estimote:sdk:1.0.3@aar'` to the dependencies of my build.gradle file but i get only `com.estimote.coresdk.*`
and the `com.estimote.mgmtsdk.*`, and not the `com.estimote.sdk.*`, which i suppose is the fully-fledged SDK.

Where am I wrong? How do I get the full SDK? (I have an Estimote Cloud account with -for now- a single Estimote assigned)

EDIT: Actually CoreSDK is the new package inside the Estimote SDK (not the old one, as I thought). So yup, if you get the CoreSDK you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

**Installation**

Add this line to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.estimote:sdk:1.0.11'
}
```

---

**Initializing Estimote SDK**

Initialize Estimote SDK in your Application class `onCreate()` method:

```
//  To get your AppId and AppToken you need to create new application in Estimote Cloud.
EstimoteSDK.initialize(applicationContext, appId, appToken);
// Optional, debug logging.
EstimoteSDK.enableDebugLogging(true);
```

---

For [more](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) information check the `README.md`

Comment: I get a "Failed to resolve: com.estimote:sdk:1.0.11", but the compile 'com.estimote:sdk:1.0.3@aar' works just fine.

And yes, I initialized it.